# Many to many relation with keeping old database

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony

I have to rewrite application from zf1 to sf2.
But I need to keep old database schema.
And I have problem with many to many relations.

There are 2 entities: Exceptions, Regions and it was too Exceptionregions, but I deleted it. 
There are 3 tables in database - exceptions, regions and exceptionregions, which is hash table.
Below I attach screen with relations:

[image: screen with relations]

My code:
1. Exception entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Exceptions
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Exceptions")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Exceptions
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ExceptionID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $exceptionid;

/**
 * Many exceptions have many regions.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Regions", inversedBy="exceptions")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="exceptionregions"),
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="ExceptionID", referencedColumnName="ExceptionID")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="RegionID", referencedColumnName="RegionID")}
 * )
 */   
private $regions; 

public function __construct()
{
    $this->regions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add region
 *
 * @param AppBundle\Entity\Regions $region
 */
public function addRegion(\AppBundle\Entity\Regions $regions)
{
    $this->regions[] = $regions;
}

/**
 * Get regions
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRegions()
{
    return $this->regions;
}

...

}
```

2. Region entity:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace AppBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * Regions
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="Regions")
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
   class Regions
   {

   /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="RegionName", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
   */
   private $regionname;

   /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="RegionID", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
   private $regionid;

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Exceptions", mappedBy="regions")
   */
   private $exceptions;

   ...
   }
   ```

And I got this error:

```
The column id must be mapped to a field in class AppBundle\Entity\Exceptions since it is referenced by a join column of another class.
```

Of course entity Exceptions is connected with few entities, not only regions.
I got stuck with this issue, I can't resolve this problem and continue my project.
Anybody has any idea how to repair this or any advice? What am I doing wrong?
I'd be grateful for any comment.

Comment: I don't see the column id defined anywhere in your code. Either you haven't shown us the code, or maybe you didn't clear the cache. Use: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` to clear your production cache.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk Thanks for the comment. Cache is cleared. The ids in these tables are called as RegionID and ExceptionID (in entities properties: regionid and exceptionid). I know probably the problem is with the name of the id, but I can't change them. What to do to make it working with these names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.
Maybe someone will benefit from this too.

So, the working code:

```
/**
 * Many exceptions have many regions.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Regions", inversedBy="exceptions")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="exceptionregions",
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ExceptionID", referencedColumnName="ExceptionID")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="RegionID", referencedColumnName="RegionID")
 *  })
 */   
private $regions;
```

@Alvin, thank you for your commitment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the relation bi-directional like so:

```
class Exceptions{
...
    /**
     * Many exceptions have many regions.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Regions", inversedBy="exceptions")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="regions_exceptions")
     */   
    private $regions;
```

---

```
class Regions{
...
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Exceptions", mappedBy="regions")
    */
    private $exceptions;
```

Not sure if that will work, but can you try it.

Documentation here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

** EDIT #2 **
Can you try this change:

```
class Exceptions
{

   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="ExceptionID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $exceptionid;
```

Also, if that doesn't work, try:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried bi-directional and unidirectional relation. The both give me the same result, the error which I have mentioned above. In my opinion the problem is the name of the id.

Comment: I made an edit. Can you try the Edit #2 changes. Just trying to help. I'm at a loss for what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, I really appreciate this. I'm confused too. But changing variable's scope doesn't work too, unfortunately. Updating schema gives me the same result.